# does the firebase database online editor ignore security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have rules set up that ensure a foreign key like constraint: when I put data at a certain path, the key is validated to exist at another node.

Rule snippet:

```
"app": {
  "freebies": {
     "$provider_id": {
          ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('app').child('providers').child($provider_id).val() != null"
        }
      }
```

}

If I run a simulation with these params

Write to `/app/freebies`
width data: `{"totally_fake": 1}`

This fails, which is CORRECT.

On the other hand, if I just go to the online editor and add a node to the same location with the same data, **it writes the DB without errors**.

My question is: does the online editor bypass the security rules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. The Firebase console, as well as the Admin SDKs, bypass security rules and have "administrative" access to the Realtime Database.

Comment: thanks for the fast response Michael ! Love your product.

Comment: I thought it was my rules that was out of order. I think this should be stated when writing rules in the console or uploading to the storage. Might be obvious for some – was not to me.